# Perl argument passing to a function

Tags: perl, split, arguments

I have written a small test script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $head="a b";

sub test
{
my @arr=split / /,@_;
print $arr[0];
}

test $head;
```

the output is `1` instead i am actually expecting `a`. Can anyone tell me where am i wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operands of `split` are evaluated in scalar context, and `@_` in scalar context evaluates to the number of elements in `@_` (`1`). You want

```
sub test {
   my @arr = split / /, $_[0];
   print $arr[0];
}
```